# "In the day" vs. "in the daytime"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to use the phrase *in the day* meaning in the daytime? For example:

> I like to go fishing **in the day** when there are no mosquitos.

Is there a chance in the day could be slightly different in meaning tham *in the daytime*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *this specific context*, there seems to be no difference.

The word "day" can mean so many different things:

- A 24-hour period of time beginning at midnight and ending at midnight (eg a calendar date)
- Any 24-hour period
- The time you are at work (a "working day") or are engaged in any other specific activity
- Any period of time, such as person's youth (eg "in my day") or their entire lifetime (eg "in Shakespeare's day")

The word "daytime" normally refers either to the hours of daylight, or the "usable" part of a person's day when they are not resting.

In your specific example though, the word "day" is qualified by stating it is the period of time where there no mosquitos. This would be understood as being the daylight hours, so really it doesn't matter too much what word you use.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! What if I asked someone "what do you like to do in the day", would it mean the same as "what do you like to do in the daytime?